# Uploading files to S3 in Spring boot and getting stored them in classpath

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I have method to upload files from user to S3 bucket. But when I'm testing it, it is both saved on S3 buckend and in my classpath.
This is my function to upload file:

```
    public void uploadFileToNews(byte[] file, String fileName) {
    File fileToSave = new File(fileName);
    try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave) ) {
        fileOutputStream.write(file);
        amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("gwnews", fileName, fileToSave));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error during uploading file to S3", e);
    }
}
```

And this is function in my service:

```
    public News addNewsImage(MultipartFile multipartFile, String newsId) throws IOException {
    News news = getById(newsId);
    news.setImageUrl(news.getId() + ".png");
    fileService.uploadFileToNews(multipartFile.getBytes(), news.getId() + ".png");
    return newsRepository.save(news);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I avoid saving file to my classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is saving the content in your classpath : "fileOutputStream.write(file);"
And the next line is saving it in your S3 bucket for corresponding AWS account.